# Unable to use latest release of miktex.exe on windows 10

Tags: miktex, windows

ERROR DETAILS
Program: miktex.exe
Error: The executed process did not succeed.
Details:
fileName: C:\Users\vs\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex.exe
exitCode: 1

Comment: Try Overleaf :)

Comment: What did the command line look like? What were you trying to do?